# Finder allows rename on Exposing desktop

Tags: snow-leopard, finder, expose, macos

When I press F11, It directly shows me the current-desktop of OSX.

Now, Let me describe the issue ( which is an issue according to me ).

Step 1) open any finder window ( for example as follows. Here, I have selected 4.1 )
[image]

Step 2) Press F11 to bring the desktop

Step 3) Now, press enter ( which is basically for renaming if a folder/file is selected in finder screen )

Observe following screen[image]

Now, My question is as follows.

- Should OSX allow renaming even in expose mode ?
- Should OSX set focus to desktop when user Presses F11 ?

Comment: http://bugreporter.apple.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug. Basically it's not setting focus onto the desktop, the focus is still on the Folder/File that you're renaming in the Finder window, the only difference is the Window is being 'drawn' off screen. If you do it then press F11 to slide it back in the rename box points will be a perfect fit.

It probably shouldn't allow it, and I've never even seen it before, so kudos for finding a pretty bizarre bug!